# Return SelectedIndex From Select Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, selectedindex

Is it possible to that have the `selectedIndex` return -1 if nothing is selected, rather than the element-text at position 0.

Also the `selectedIndex` returns 0 even if nothing is selected.

```
<select id="qwe" name="qwe">
    <option>11</option>
    <option>22</option>
</select>   

document.someForm.qwe.value
//returns 11

$('#qwe option:selected').val()
//returns 11



<select id="qwe" name="qwe">
    <option selected="false">11</option>
    <option>22</option>
</select>   
$('#qwe option:selected').val()
//returns 11

<select id="qwe" name="qwe">
    <option selected="false">11</option>
    <option selected="false">22</option>
</select>   
$('#qwe option:selected').val()
//returns 22
```

Comment: Add an <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option> to your list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select boxes must always have a value selected (by default the first option). If you want such a behavior, just add an empty option to the top of your list, with whatever value ( eg -1 ) you want.

Comment: Except for empty `<select>` elements. Their `selectedIndex` is -1. Not important, just wanted to throw that out there :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add a default first option...  Just use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) and change the `selectedIndex`:

```
$('#qwe').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/j76yH/2/

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
    <select id="demo">
      <option value="-1">---</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">1</option>
    </select>
```

As hexblot said, every selectbox has a selected value. Always.. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following statement:

```
if ($('#qwe option[selected="selected"]').val() === undefined) return -1;
```